# Calculating Hit Time of a Homing Missile and Moving Target

Tags: game-physics, physics

I am trying to calculate hit time of a missile to a moving target. First of all, let me make some clarifications.

- Assume everything is in 2D.
- Moving target means, the target is moving along a curve, which is represented by a collection of waypoints. The target's velocity has a fixed magnitude.
- The missile has a fixed speed. In each FRAME/TICK, it moves towards the target position.

So, the missile has no prediction system, it blindly moves toward the target and will ALWAYS hit the target.

If the target is moving, the missile will make a non-linear movement in total, as it will curve towards the target.

- My goal is to find the exact hit time of the missile against this target. I already have a solution to the problem, but i want to increase the efficiency of the solution.

My solution is to "simulate" the time by fixed intervals, moving object and missile in each simulation tick, then checking for collision, then moving to the next tick. As you can imagine, this will never fail but it requires computational power, as I am aiming for less than 50 millisecond error, I need to use small interval to simulate.

The main problem with this solution happens when the target and missile is far away from each other, we simulate lots of ticks. If I increase the simulation interval to reduce the simulated ticks, the missile is making more linear path than the reality and this will cause inaccuracy.

I would like to know if anyone can think of an O(1) solution for this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: idk anything abt game physics but cant u just math out the solution?

Comment: Actually, yes, there seems to be some kind of an explicit formula, but its derivation is a bit involved. Are you still interested? If you are, then I will write a sketch of how one can derive it. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried to derive the mathematical model of your missile flight requirements and used it to obtain an algorithm that calculates the time of impact you seek. It is a good idea to double check the calculations because they are a bit involved.

Let's start with the mathematical model of the case when the target is flying along a straight line with constant velocity.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, one can use the formulas derived above to construct an algorithm that calculates the time of impact as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
I checked your calculations, but I didn't see where you are accounting for the PATH of the target. You seem to have made a solution for the case where target is always moving towards the same direction, but in the question I talked about "collection of waypoints". Which means target will move towards different directions as the time goes on, but the speed of the movement will always be fixed.
Still, your answer is inspiring and I will try to derive something using it.

Comment: @AnılAkkaya Hold on, your post is very unclear then. You are talking about the target moving along a linear path and constant speed. What does that mean? Linear path usually means a path that is a line and constant speed means moving along a line with constant speed. I do not know what the term waypoints mean. You need to be much more precise in describing the situation you are dealing with. If the target is moving in a general way, then you cannot calculate anything explicit. Only numerics will work.

Comment: @AnılAkkaya So basically you can still write everything I wrote, just have to think of  `alpha` as a function of time. And then you see that you cannot solve the differential equations explicitly.

Comment: Sorry for my vague explanation in the original post.  

Waypoints:  Collection of 2D points.  (If you have programming experience, you can think of it as vector<point> or list<point>)

So in a given time, target's movement is represented as a linear movement towards one of the waypoints with a constant speed. Once the target reaches his target waypoint, it's starts a new movement to the next waypoint in the list.

So at any time, we need 3 things to understand the object movement: next waypoint index, current position, and all waypoints.

Comment: What I tried to say with the term linear path is that target's waypoint list is generally very small and targets path is very long, so the movement itself can be analyzed by analyzing each of the 'segments' (segment here means a movement between 2 points with constant speed). 
For example, when I calculate hit time of non-homing missiles to the target, I check for possible solution for each segment. 
I couldn't apply the same solution to the homing missile because of the weirdness of the missile movement, as it depends on the object position at any given time.

Comment: @AnılAkkaya I strongly recommend you edit your post and write all of these explanations there. The comments are not the place to be clarifying the pots and adding such important and crucial details. If clarification is needed, edit the post and add the clarifications. I have updated my answer now and have provided an outline for an algorithm that can achieve your goal.